# Assigning string to char pointer in 64bit error

Tags: c++, string, pointers, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I am stuck in a problem assigning a string to a character pointer. It seemed that the character pointer is taking only first 256 character of the string. My working in 64bit platform. Also the same code works fine for 32bit platform. I couldn't figure out why only 256 character is only being assigned in a char pointer variable in 64 bit platform could anyone please help.. Thank in advance.

My tests are

```
const char *test2=
    "Hello everyone"
    "Please help me"
    "my string assigning part to char pointer in a code is not working"
    "I have been stucked on it for 3 days."
    "I tried lot of things"
    "but the problem persists."
    "I have no idea why the code is not working"
    " Here comes The problem in next line..."
    "If you get this line in the up assigning variable..yuppieee";

const char *test3="Hello everyone .Please help me my string assigning part to char pointer in a code is not working I have been stucked on it for 3 days. I tried lot of things but the problem persists. I have no idea why the code is not working  Here comes The problem in next line... If you get this line in the up assigning variable..yuppieee";
```

Result in

```
test2 ="Hello everyonePlease help memy string assigning part to char pointer in a code is not workingI have been stucked on it for 3 days.I tried lot of thingsbut the problem persists.I have no idea why the code is not working Here comes The problem in next line.."

test3 ="Hello everyone .Please help me my string assigning part to char pointer in a code is not working I have been stucked on it for 3 days. I tried lot of things but the problem persists. I have no idea why the code is not working  Here comes The problem in nex"
```

only first 256 character is assinged to the variable.

Code

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

const char *test3="Hello everyone .Please help me my string assigning part to char pointer in a code is not working I have been stucked on it for 3 days. I tried lot of things but the problem persists. I have no idea why the code is not working  Here comes The problem in next line... If you get this line in the up assigning variable..yuppieee";

cout<<test3<<endl<<endl;
getch();
return 0;

}
```

the project is set to contain common language support runtime(/clr) in project properties in vs2005 in 64bit compile mode.

Comment: When you say 'resulted in' how are you inspecting the strings? Show us the code...

Comment: Also, you might wish to add which compiler you are using.

Comment: If you check the variable in a debugger, it might actually be the debugger that limits the contents it can show. But you really should show a complete program, or we can't possibly answer this question. Please make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and edit your question to include it.

Comment: I used text visualizer in visual studio. I am using visual studio 2005. and working on 64 bit platform. the assigning works fine when checked in 32bit compile. also the text visualizer shows the whole data assigned correctly in 32 bit.. but in 64 bit it shows truncated data only.

Comment: Try just using `cout << test2 << endl` to write the text to the console, or performing a `strlen` to get the actual length of the string - not what you are seeing in the debugger (the debugger is necessarily different for 64 and 32 bit code, btw).

Comment: The result value when the project is set to have no  clr support show whole text2 characters but when clr support is enabled in the project only first 256 character is displayed. 
so the problem is with the clr support. 
I want it to work with clr support. I am totally stucked with it. :-(